# Give different values to numbers

Tags: c#

I'm a bit confused here, although I'm sure the answer will be simple. I want to add different values to different numbers, but how can this be achieved simply?

Example: 1 = 10, 3 = 20, 5 = 30. If user enters the number 4, the answer would be 60. Because 2 didn't had any specific value, it should also be 10. Number 2 also needs 10 as a value because it comes after 1 and doesn't get a new value. The value changes at number 3 to 20, and from then on the values of every number after it is 20 until a new value is assigned to a higher number. Then number 4 needs to be 20 again, because the value didn't change yet, and number 5 needs to get a value of 50.

Another example:

```
    Numers entered by user: 10

    Values:
    1 = 10
    5 = 20
    8 = 30

    In this case, the values of all the 10 numbers should be:
    1 = 10
    2 = 10
    3 = 10
    4 = 10
    5 = 20
    6 = 20
    7 = 20
    8 = 20
    9 = 30
    10 = 30
```

So the answer would be: 180 (all combined values).

Comment: Hold on... 4 should be remapped to 60, but to 20 if it comes after three..? And because it "didn't change" _which_ value? I've already provided an answer, but I'm now not sure I understood your question correctly after all. It's a bit unclear what you are actually asking - could you provide a better description, and more examples of what you expect?

Comment: @Kjartan I've updated the opening post, hopefully it's a little more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample contains tricky error: instead of  `8 = 20` should be  `8 = 30` so actual answer is `190`

Below is the code to calculate Totals based on your sample. Hope it helps

```
// Following lines should be replaced with actual input method
int TotalNumber = 10;
List<Tuple<int, int>> CheckPoints = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

CheckPoints.Add(Tuple.Create(1, 10));
CheckPoints.Add(Tuple.Create(5, 20));
CheckPoints.Add(Tuple.Create(8, 30));


int NumberTillCount = 10;//determines point till which calculation should proceed

int result = 0;
Tuple<int, int> CurrentCheckPoint = new Tuple<int,int>(0,0);

//Loop checks if new CheckPoint is encountered and writes it in temp variable 'CurrentCheckPoint'
for (int i = 1; i <= NumberTillCount; i++)
{
    CurrentCheckPoint = CheckPoints.FindIndex(x=>x.Item1 == i) != -1 ? CheckPoints.Find(x=>x.Item1 == i) : CurrentCheckPoint;
    result += CurrentCheckPoint.Item2;
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you very much! I'm going to study it a bit more. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use `Dictionary<int, int>` for this, so `key` will be an user input, a `value` - associated "response".

```
IDictionary<int, int> map = new Dictionary<int, int>();
map.Add(1, 10);
map.Add(3, 20);


public int GetResponseForUserInput(int input)
{
   int response = -1;
   if (map.ContainsKey(input))
   {
      response = map[input];
   }

   return response;
}
```

Comment: I tested the script but it doesn't work. All the numbers between the ones that have a value are -1.

Comment: @user1931912 and it's exactly how it should work. You must add `map.Add(UserInputNumber, ReturnedValue);` for **each** desired input

Comment: @Nogard You're telling me that I must write 10.000 map.Add statements for every single digit that I want to use? Number 2 also needs 10 as a value because it comes after 1 and doesn't get a new value. The value changes at number 3 to 20, and from then on the values of every number after it is 20 until a new value is assigned to a higher number.

Comment: @user1931912 Yes I do as your question is highly confusive. What I  understood is that you have static dependence between numbers. From your current comment it's finnaly obvious you have some dynamic logic - please provide clear description of it in your initial question

Comment: @Nogard I changed the OP. All the numbers needs to be mapped with the same value as the last number that had a fixed value. If a higher number changes the value, that value need to apply to all numbers after that one, until a new number comes up with another new value.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you could do is probably to just implement a method with a switch-structure, like this:

```
public int getNumber(int inputNr)
{
    var returnNr = 1;

    switch (inputNr)
    {
        case 1:
            returnNr = 10;
            break;
        case 3:
            returnNr = 30;
            break;
        case 4:
            returnNr = 60;
            break;
        default:
            // Probably not needed, as default returnNr is 1.
            break;
    }

    return returnNr;
}
```

Edit: On second thought, this is even easier:

```
// Place the values in positions according to when you want them as results:
int[] numbers = {1, 10, 1, 30, 60};  

public int getNumber(int inputNr){
    return numbers.GetValue(inputNr); // Return the value at position "inputNr".
}
```

Comment: the `switch` solution has few drawbacks:   1) All dependences are hard-coded and cannot be changed at runtime  2) Possible scaling to even 20+ choices will make this very bulky and difficult to maintain

Comment: Same result as the poster above. Number 2 also needs 10 as a value because it comes after 1 and doesn't get a new value. The value changes at number 3 to 20, and from then on the values of every number after it is 20 until a new value is assigned to a higher number.

Comment: I'm fully aware of the drawbacks here, but this was a fairly simple question, so it calls for a simple solution, based on an assumed small set of input numbers to show a simple principle. A better solution for a bigger system might be to use a database-table or something like it to map between input- and output numbers, but that might be slightly beyond the scope here ;)

Comment: @user1931912 Please see my comment under you original question. I'll try to update my answer when it is a little more clear what you actually need! :)

Comment: Thanks Kjartan, I will keep my eye on it. :)